# Pythonic way for inline replace string in one single line?

Tags: python

Is there a more pythonic and elegant way to replace multiple times a string without doing this in a list?

I want need to do multiple replaces with a string.
So.

```
s = 'Helloooo'
pattern = ["a",, "b", "c"]

new = [s.replace(p, "") for p in patterns)]
```

This gives a list and I do not want to waste more lines with a for loop...

What is possible with python like?

```
new = s.replace(p, "") for p in patterns
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean exactly with  "replace multiple times a string without doing this in a list" ?

Comment: You want to replace multiple characters from a string, am I right?

Comment: [re,sub()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) can do this.

Comment: or multiple substrings from the same string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `re.sub(...)` combined with a `join` of your patterns:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'abc'
>>> patterns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> re.sub(rf'{"|".join(patterns)}', '', s)
''
>>> re.sub(rf'{"|".join(patterns)}', '', 'dabcd')
'dd'
```

Comment: As you see you have multiple strign amde from a single string

Comment: I want to perform multiple replaces on the single string to get out the same single string not multiple differnt copies...

Comment: So your example should give the empty string s=""

Comment: OK cool, then I'd recommend going with `re.sub(...)` and compiling a regular expression with `join`, I've updated the answer.

Comment: thanks! Could please expalin what the symbols like rf mean? I

Comment: Thanks. Could you have a look here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66802129/replacing-html-tags-for-any-attributes