# replacing html tags for any attributes

Tags: python

what is the most canonical way to replace a specific tag but which can have arbitrary classes. So.

```
<li class="XYZ ...> -> *
```

I want to replace any kind of li's with a *

Also I cannot be sure that after classes there are no other attributes.

Si I need something like:

```
tag.replace("<li \* >", "*")
```

wher this \* should be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
st = '<li class="class1" id="id1" ...</li>'
print(re.sub('<li(.*?)</li>', '*', st))
```